# amp using focus and blur on input elements

Tags: input, focus, amp-html, setstate

I'm pretty new on AMP, and I've built a few pages, so bear with me if I sound silly.

I have an input box, and I want to trigger some classes on other elements with focusing and blurring the input.

Here's an example code I have written for the input:

```
<input type="text" id="selectedFilter_SearchBox"
     on="focus:AMP.setState({isFocued: true}),
         focus:AMP.setState({isFocued: false})"/>
```

And here's what I have for the element I want to be triggered by focusing the input:

```
<div class="test" [class]="isFocued ? 'test focused' : 'test'">
.....
</div>
```

I should mention that these elements are pretty far from each other on DOM, so using CSS (+ and ~) is impossible.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Currently, the focus event can be simulated by using tap event, but that only works for mouse and not the tab key.

[Here is the reference Issue link](https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/issues/11248)

You can achieve your goal by css also [Working Url](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/wXZaBg)

**Code**

```
<!doctype html>
<html ⚡>
 <head>
   <meta charset="utf-8">
   <link rel="canonical" href="you-link-or-same-page.html">
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,minimum-scale=1,initial-scale=1">
   <style amp-boilerplate>body{-webkit-animation:-amp-start 8s steps(1,end) 0s 1 normal both;-moz-animation:-amp-start 8s steps(1,end) 0s 1 normal both;-ms-animation:-amp-start 8s steps(1,end) 0s 1 normal both;animation:-amp-start 8s steps(1,end) 0s 1 normal both}@-webkit-keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}@-moz-keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}@-ms-keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}@-o-keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}@keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}</style><noscript><style amp-boilerplate>body{-webkit-animation:none;-moz-animation:none;-ms-animation:none;animation:none}</style></noscript>
   <script async src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0.js"></script>
     <style amp-custom>
    .test { display:none;}
    #selectedFilter_SearchBox:focus + .test { display:block; }
  </style>
</head>
 <body>
 <input type="text" id="selectedFilter_SearchBox" /> 
   <p class="test">
    Your content here .....
  </p>
  </body>
</html>
```